# FBRequest dialogue problems

Tags: ios, facebook, request, dialog

I'm trying to have my iOS send app requests to Facebook friends. I'm using request dialogue.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
  NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                          // Optional parameter for sending request directly to user
                          // with UID. If not specified, the MFS will be invoked
                          @"RECIPIENT_USER_ID", @"to",  

                          // Give the structured request information
                          @"send", @"action_type",           
                          @"YOUR_OBJECT_ID", @"object_id", 

                             nil];

[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!"
 title:nil
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
];
```

I have used the correct IDs. It's not giving me any error but it's also not doing anything. Please help.

Comment: Have you already logged into facebook within the app and have a valid session?

Comment: Yes. Session is valid, permissions are requested, objects made in the developer page on Facebook.